# Numpy syntax to assign elements of an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to create an array whose elements are a function of their position.
Something like

```
N = 1000000 
newarray = np.zeros([N,N,N])
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        for k in range(N):
            newarray[i,j,k] = f(i,j,k)
```

Is there a way to increase the speed of this operation, by removing the for loops / parallelizing it using the numpy syntax?

This is the f function

`def f(i,j,k):
   indices = (R[:,0]==i) *( R[:,1]==j) * (R[:,2]==k)
   return M[indices]`

where for example

`R = np.random.randint(0,N,[N,3])
 M = np.random.randn(N)*15`

and in the actual application they are not random.

Comment: Only if you show `f`

Comment: Alternatively, if the function allows broadcasting, you can do - `f(np.ogrid[:N,:N,:N])`.

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: f is something like 
`indices = (R[:,0]==i) *( R[:,1]==j) * (R[:,2]==k)`


            `return np.mean(
                M[indices] 
            )
`

Comment: @JohnBrown Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56238202/edit) to add that instead of a comment

Comment: @RickM.  Right, just edited

Comment: An array of that size (`(1000000, 1000000, 1000000))`) would take in the order of [exabytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exabyte) of space. Surely you are not actually trying to create something like that?

Comment: the number was an example just to show that it is _big_ in some sense

Comment: Is it guaranteed that `indices` in `f` will have one and only `True` value? That is, will there not be repeated rows in `R`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that operation with the [`at`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) method of [`np.add`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.add.html):

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
N = 100
R = np.random.randint(0, N, [N, 3])
M = np.random.randn(N) * 15
newarray = np.zeros([N, N, N])
np.add.at(newarray, (R[:, 0], R[:, 1], R[:, 2]), M)
```

In this case, if `R` has any repeated row the corresponding value in `newarray` will be the sum of all the corresponding values in `M`.

EDIT: To take the average instead of sum for repeated elements you could do something like this:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
N = 100
R = np.random.randint(0, N, [N, 3])
M = np.random.randn(N) * 15
newarray = np.zeros([N, N, N])
np.add.at(newarray, (R[:, 0], R[:, 1], R[:, 2]), M)
newarray_count = np.zeros([N, N, N])
np.add.at(newarray_count, (R[:, 0], R[:, 1], R[:, 2]), 1)
m = newarray_count > 1
newarray[m] /= newarray_count[m]
```

Comment: is it possible to take the average instead of the sum?

Comment: @JohnBrown I added another possible snippet for that.

Comment: thank you, this sounds reasonable, however it is a really slow solution.

Comment: @JohnBrown For the last part for the means on the second snippet, the advanced indexing may be more expensive than just operating on the whole array. Try replacing the last two lines with `np.clip(newarray_count, 1, None, out=newarray_count); newarray /= newarray_count`.